# How to fetch only name between /name/name using regex

Tags: asp.net, regex

```
   031 AF/FA 016-7243616966-67/ETUA/USD1026.47/18APR13/                       
    DCA1S211E/49881134/UA 216 T 28APR MIAEWR/UA8838 T 28APR                
    EWRFRA/LH1306 T 29APR FRABEY/LH1309 L 26MAY BEYFRA/                    
    UA8849 L 26MAY FRAMIA/CHEHABEDDINE/JOUMANA                             
   031 RF-SZ CR-DCA1S211E 49881134 SU 0105SZ/RO-67EBA3C0 DCA1S2               
    10W 49592222 18APR2221Z
```

How to fetch only name like /CHEHABEDDINE/JOUMANA and not any of the string from this string
using regex at present

I'am using `/\w*\/\w*` regex

Comment: You should define the rules, as far I can see you may use `[A-Z]{4,}` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yC3bP3) which is the closest to your needs. Maybe you should edit your Q ?

Comment: @HamZa: That, and a clarification why it's not `FRAMIA/CHEHABEDDINE` that should be matched.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I don't want to ruin the mood, but `CHEHABEDDINE` is a person's name. So I'm afraid he wants to get all the names from a string which is impossible for a regex without rules ...

Comment: @HamZa: Sure, that's what I meant.

Comment: yup hamza u r rite thats a name which i want to fetch by using regex

Comment: @amitesh Like we said you need to define the rules, for example does it begin with `/` ? Are the letters always +4 of length ? I mean there are some names that are not so long for example `Mi`. Review your strategy and maybe we could help you. Otherwise you would check against a list of names to know if it's a desired one...

Comment: see hamza this is a just a single string from my string array the thing is that its name which i want to fetch and name may vary and yes it always start with / but string letter may vary

Comment: and second thing there are many / symbol that why i cant use \/(.+?)/ regex

Comment: @amitesh this is [the best](http://regex101.com/r/nA4gB2) I can come up with `(?<=\/)[A-Z]{5,}`. This will match uppercase letters that are min 5 characters long and preceded with `/`.

Comment: its not almost work for me but yes may be this will help me

Comment: As a remark: `\w` matches alphanumeric characters, so numbers as well.

Comment: @HamZa, I think that your regex matches separately `CHEHABEDDINE` and `JOUMANA` and not `/CHEHABEDDINE/JOUMANA`

Comment: @polkduran Yeah it does, and I would think that's the desired result (for what he has provided until now)

Comment: @HamZa ok, so if he wants to match the names separately your regex works

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
(?:\/[a-zA-Z]+){2}\b
```

http://regex101.com/r/aZ7qS2

**[Edit]**

To match `/name/otherName`

**[Edit2]**

And if you want to match the names separately try this:

```
\/([a-zA-Z]+)\/([a-zA-Z]+)\b
```

http://regex101.com/r/kQ7vZ3